# Get Orders that employes have worked on

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So i am having a hard time doing what i want to do, basicly i have 2 Google sheets, one with orders, and one with employes, what i am trying to do is, on the employes sheet, i want to go to the orders sheet with FILTER() and IMPORTRANGE() and get all orders that X employe worked on, and i know how to do that if one employe only works in one Order, the problem is if i have 2 employes working on the same order, is that even possible?

[image: Orderns Sheet]

This is what i want to get
[image: Employe Sheet]

This is how i am getting the Order list on the Employe Sheet if i only have 1 employe on an order and it works fine:

`=FILTER( IMPORTRANGE(VLOOKUP('Orders url';Orders!$A:$B;2;);"Registo!$A$2:$K");   IMPORTRANGE(VLOOKUP('Orders url';Orders!$A:$B;2;);"Registo!$C$2:$C")=A2 )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=FILTER(
  IMPORTRANGE(VLOOKUP('Orders url';Orders!$A:$B;2;);"Registo!$A$2:$K"); 
  MAP(
    IMPORTRANGE(VLOOKUP('Orders url';Orders!$A:$B;2;);"Registo!$C$2:$C"); 
    LAMBDA(empl; NOT(ISNA(MATCH(A2; SPLIT(empl; ","); 0))))
  )
)
```

In case you use employee ids, it will avoid "collisions", for example, matching orders of employee `1` when employee `12` worked on the order.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with REGEXMATCH, FIND or SEARCH. The first one can be a little tricky if you have special characters, but if you don't you can use it like this:

```
=FILTER( IMPORTRANGE(VLOOKUP('Orders url';Orders!$A:$B;2;);"Registo!$A$2:$K");
   REGEXMATCH(IMPORTRANGE(VLOOKUP('Orders url';Orders!$A:$B;2;);"Registo!$C$2:$C"),A2 ))
```

With FIND you'll find the value case-sensitive. You'll need to use IFERROR in case it's not found:

```
=FILTER( IMPORTRANGE(VLOOKUP('Orders url';Orders!$A:$B;2;);"Registo!$A$2:$K");
       IFERROR(FIND(IMPORTRANGE(VLOOKUP('Orders url';Orders!$A:$B;2;);"Registo!$C$2:$C"),A2 )))
```

And SEARCH is case-insensitive:

```
=FILTER( IMPORTRANGE(VLOOKUP('Orders url';Orders!$A:$B;2;);"Registo!$A$2:$K");
       IFERROR(SEARCH(IMPORTRANGE(VLOOKUP('Orders url';Orders!$A:$B;2;);"Registo!$C$2:$C"),A2 )))
```